# Formatting Seaborn x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm having an issue with my x-axis being too crowded and also have the label numbers not seem to correspond with their actual position on the graph, but instead with the X data values. My data is formatted as a pandas DataFrame like so (there's more but this is representative):

```
    Y       X1
2   3.81    51.000  
12  1.95    2.000   
13  2.97    20.600  
18  3.66    23.472  
23  4.45    40.100  
27  6.57    90.800  
28  6.28    77.500  
35  2.44    5.000   
43  1.55    4.700   
50  2.80    17.800  
53  3.40    61.200
```

Using the following method, my plot looks like this:

```
g = sns.regplot(x=X1, y=Y, marker='+', ci=None)
```

[image]

I've tried using

```
g = sns.regplot(x=X1, y=Y, marker='+', ci=None)
num_ticks = 10
g.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=num_ticks)
```

[image]

As you can see, it lets me set the number of ticks, but the value labels are completely wrong. They seem to correspond as to an ordered list of the X-values for the data points, which makes no sense to me why seaborn would choose that instead of interpreting the ticks as the actual X value at the tick position.

By expanding adding the following line, I was able to get a little closer, but even the labels seem to get screwed up in rounding somewhere, even with the round function:

```
g.set_xticklabels(np.arange(x_min, x_max, round((x_max-x_min)/num_ticks, 1)))
```

[image]

I realize at this point I can manually convert to strings and pass it a series of string labels, but that seems like a crap solution. Is there is a better way to go about this? The fact that I'm spending an hour or more just trying to format my axis correctly feels like I must be missing something critical and simple.

As a secondary question, I'm not convinced that even when I fix the rounding issue here if I'll be happy with the output, as it can be hard to understand the graph when the ticks are odd intervals instead of something more familiar (e.g. 5, 10, 20, etc). What would another generic solution look like that would allow me to easily format the axis to be these numbers and have the data/number of ticks adjust automatically to the interval I'm looking for? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: what happen when you change figure size?

Comment: Because `regplot` itself works fine, you probably just forgot to convert your dataframe to actual numbers.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest This isn't an exact duplicate of another question. Taking the dtype of the internal data provides dtype: float64. I've determined what the issue was, or at least a fix action, and if you'll unlock this, I can self-answer so other people with this type of problem will be able to reference this and learn from the solution, or provide additional discussion on why my initial attempt was not effective.